# Rewrite Query String with .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a very simple rewrite of a query string

```
http://www.example.com/library.php?q=abscessed-tooth
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/library/abscessed-tooth
```

This is the code that I've written in my .htaccess file and it is doing nothing

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/library/?([^/]*)/?\/http://www.example.com/library.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What's the resulting url after rewriting? Or is it not rewriting at all? Please be more specific to what your problem is exactly.

Comment: It is not rewriting at all.. this is what i have written in my htaccess file

RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^library/([^/]*) http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library.php?q=$1 [L]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe likely .htaccess files are not considered in your environment. If in doubt turn on RewriteLogging as it is explained in the excellent documentation of the rewriting module.

Oh, and check the error log, you have a syntax error in the RewriteRule anyway: `RewriteRule` takes 2 arguments plus flags, your rule has only a single argument:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^library/([^/]*) http://www.example.com/library.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need dollar sign in the end of "left" part not question mark:

```
^/library/([^/]*)/$ http://www.example.com/library.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Also do you need the question mark between / and ( ? It doesn't look like lookahead or lookbehind?

Try without wrapping slashes as well

```
^library/([^/]*)$ http://www.example.com/library.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Acutally i am trying it out on our demo server and its not working there . I guess may be the domain can be an issue.

http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library.php?q=abscessed-tooth

Comment: You have to add slashes to your internal files, css, js and images, for example:

/sbtemplates/1072/css/layout.css

Comment: Do i have to give the absolute pathnames before the files?

Comment: yes, it won't hurt if you're on "first" level, but it's necessary if you go "deeper". Of course you can avoid it by doing some magic in htaccess, but it's your preference

Comment: I did but still its not happening . This is i have in my htaccess file

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^library/([^/]*) http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library.php?q=$1 [L]

Comment: Everything looks fine when I visit: http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library/abscessed-tooth

Comment: Its Working now but i want to know there are many other pages which is not using query strings so they are being grouped under library too..

for example :

Link given in an anchor tag : http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/contact.php

is changed to 

http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library/contact.php

Comment: You would need to add slashes to them as well so they are referenced /contact.php or /contact and another RewriteRule for "single" links

Comment: Can you please suggest the rewrite rule for single links?

Comment: It can be as simple as that: ^([^/]*)$ http://www.example.com/$1.php [L]

but just as a precaution you may want to allow only letters, numbers, underscores and dashes to go through, but it's up to you how far you would like to take it:

^([a-zA-z0-9\-_]*)\.(php|html|htm)$ http://www.example.com/$1.$2[L]

Comment: Its Giving Inter Server Error 500 . this is what i have in htaccess file . 

Options +FollowSymLinks   

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/$1.php [L]



RewriteRule ^library/([^/]*) http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library.php?q=$1 [L]

Comment: Try this: 

Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ 173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/$1\.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^library/([^/]*)$ 173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library.php?q=$1 [L]

Comment: I see.. You are using the absolute url on the right side, try to put it on the left as well? 

RewriteRule ^173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/([^/]*)$ 173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/$1\.php [L] 

or

RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)$ 173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/$1\.php [L] 


But actually, why are you using absolute path? isn't 173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile your default dir anyway?

Comment: yeah it is...i am trying to put on the left side as well

Comment: yeah it is...i am trying to put on the left side as well..its working now..one last question is that if you vist the site you will find a left bar or sidebar below...i have given the path names like :-


http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library.php?q=abscessed-tooth


when its clicked the url is not rewritten to :-

http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library/abscessed-tooth


My Htaccess file has:-

RewriteRule ^173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library/([^/]*)$ 173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library.php?q=$1 [L]

Comment: If that's your default dir, try to remove it from htaccess altogether. It will be much easier to add/edit. Then this should work fine: 

RewriteRule ^library/([^/]*)$ library.php?q=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ $1.php [L]

and your links in HTML/PHP should look like

/contact
/services
/offices

Comment: i should put the links like this in my anchor tag ?

<a href="http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library.php?q=Implants">Implants</a>

and for single links :-

<a href="http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/staff.php">Staff</a>

Comment: Your anchors tags should look like /contact, /services etc. 

remove ip/~newmedia/dev/allsmile from all places and take it from there

Comment: i have taken from like :- /~newmedia/dev/allsmile/staff.php 

and for the query string like this :- /~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library.php?q=Implants

this will be okay?

Comment: If I knew how your environment looks like it would be easier. but my assumption would be to just leave library.php?q=Implants. In anchors /library/Implants

Comment: the anchor is still showing q=implants in the query string..

http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library.php?q=Implants

Comment: If you do everything like that: 


HTACCESS

`Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^library/([^/]*)$ library.php?q=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ $1.php [L]`

LINKS IN YOUT HTML
`/library/abscessed-tooth
/contact
/services`

Comment: its giving a 404 page not found error if i write what you told in the htaccess file.

Comment: i gave this to my htaccess file and no error is giving but the anchor in the sidebar is showing same as library.php?q=implants

HTaccess file:-

Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^library/([^/]*)$ http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library.php?q=$1 [L] 

RewriteRule ^http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/([^/]*)$ http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/$1.php [L]

Comment: What if you change your anchor to :

`173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library/Implants`

Comment: its working but the single links are coming like this :-

http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library/staff.php

Comment: you have to change all the links to: 

`173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/allsmile/library/staff`  etc.  (without ***.php***)

Comment: Yeah Its working now...One question if i check on client server after uploading same way i have to change all the links and setup the HTACCESS file as i did it here ...?

Comment: Yes, but i would strongly advise you work on it to minimize the length of those URLs to make them as nice as possible. Good luck!